# How do I split a letter and number?

Tags: javascript

I have this string

```
let tmp = "abcd1234";
```

I tried below code but didnt worked. can anyone pls. advice.

```
let tmp = "abcd1234"; 
var alphas = tmp.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d");
console.log(alphas[0],'---',alphas[1])
```

Its returning "abcd1234 --- undefined"

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure you will have alpha, then numeric, then look for the point where it changes, append a space, then split on it :

```js
const tmp = "abcd1234";
const [alpha, numeric] = tmp.replace(/(\D)(\d)/, '$1 $2').split(' ');
console.log(alpha, '---', numeric);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is `(?<=\\D)(?=\\d`, it appears that you're missing a closing bracket `)` at the end of your regex. The complete regex then becomes `(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)`.

Also you're enclosing your regex in `"regex"` and it should be enclosed in `/regex/`

```js
let tmp = "abcd1234"; 
var alphas = tmp.split(/(?<=\D)(?=\d)/);
console.log(alphas);
console.log(alphas[0],'---',alphas[1])
```

Based on a comment by @trichetriche who said positive lookbehind is not supported on all browsers, a simpler method would be to enclose the letters and numbers within their own capturing group like this:

```js
const regex = /(\D+)(\d+)/;
const str = "abcd1234";
let alphas = regex.exec(str);

console.log(alphas[1], '---', alphas[2])
```

Comment: Although it works, positive lookbehind is not supported by every browser (yet). Just a drawback to consider, but have my upvote anyway.

Comment: True, there's probably a better way but I was just fixing what's wrong with his own created regex. Thanks

Comment: @trichetriche I've updated my answer to include an alternative method which does not use positive lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let tmp = "abcd1234";
var alphas = tmp.split(/(\d+)/);
console.log(alphas[0], '---', alphas[1])
```

simple regexp `/(\d+)/` that  will find numbers in row and split from letters

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regex too:

```
let tmp = "abcd1234"; 
let myRegexp = /([a-z]+)([1-9]+)/;
var match = myRegexp.exec(tmp);
console.log(match[1],'---',match[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use Regex? this could be a starter solution

```js
let tmp = "abcd1234"; 
var n = /\d+/.exec(tmp);
var c = /[a-zA-Z]+/.exec(tmp);
console.log(n[0],'---',c[0])
```

From here you should to control if there are multiples matches and so on.

Note: \D+ will match every caracter non digit so =+. etc will match.

More Regex info: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Regex playground : [here](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
const tmp = "abcdABCD1234";    
const [alpha, numeric] = tmp.split(/(\d+)/);    
console.log(alpha, '---', numeric);
```

Comment: Hey, please don't just post code, explain what you're doing and how it solves the problem.